# Laravel two select input in edit blade

Tags: javascript, laravel, select, edit

Hello I have two select method.
First:

```
{!! Form::select('province', ['1' => 'Dolnośląskie', '2' => 'Kujawsko-Pomorskie', '3' => 'Lubelskie', '4' => 'Lubuskie', '5' => 'Łódzkie', '6' => 'Małopolskie', '7' => 'Mazowieckie', '8' => 'Opolskie', '9' => 'Podkarpackie', '10' => 'Podlaskie', '11' => 'Pomorskie', '12' => 'Śląskie', '13' => 'Świętokrzyskie', '14' => 'Warmińsko-Mazurskie', '15' => 'Wielkopolskie', '16' => 'Zachodniopomorskie', ], $getWorker->province_id, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'prov', 'onchange' => 'giveSelection(this.value)']) !!}
```

And second:

```
  <select id="vill" class="form-control" name="city">
    @foreach($getVillages as $village)
      <option data-option={{ $village->province_id }} {{ $getWorker->city_id == $village->id ? 'selected="selected"' : '' }} value="{{ $village->id }}">{{ $village->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
  </select>
```

And Controller edit method:

```
public function edit($id) {
    $getWorker = Worker::find($id);
    $getVillages = DB::table('villages')->select('id', 'province_id', 'name')->orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();
    return view('worker.edit', compact('getWorker', 'getVillages'));
}
```

These methods are connected with each other, when I change province in first select, second select return city only with id province. Responsible for this is `data-option={{ $village->province_id }}`

This is code JS for changing the locality in the second selected (`city`):

```
  var prov = document.querySelector('#prov');
  var vill = document.querySelector('#vill');
  var prov_id = vill.querySelectorAll('option');

  function giveSelection(selValue) {
    vill.innerHTML = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < prov_id.length; i++) {
      if(prov_id[i].dataset.option === selValue) {
        vill.appendChild(prov_id[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  giveSelection(prov.value);
```

I have problem with get value `city_id`. I try used this:

```
{{ $getWorker->city_id == $village->id ? 'selected="selected"' : '' }}
```

but script JS only return me LAST city in alphabetical order.
I don't know how I can change script JS to correctly selected value.

[image]

Select option work like this: [Two HTML-select boxes linked to each other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27674022/6678345)

Comment: What do you mean with "second select return city"? the value in this select change

Comment: Second select return name of `city` based id from `province`. Look this is my table: https://images83.fotosik.pl/938/2e183d4eddb005c0gen.png. that must work like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27674022/6678345

Comment: As far as I understand the village and province mechanism is working well, the issue you have is with `selected` attribute is not being set due to the worker city_id, right?

Comment: No, the problem with `selected` city is because in JS script  I have line: `vill.appendChild(prov_id[i]);` and this return WRONG (only last) name of city (like a screen, name: Zwierzyn, Zielona Góra, Zbąszynek ... is name of city in Poland). I must change script JS to correct return name city. In the screen I have marked what should be highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

I think there was a problem outputting on `selected` attribute

```
'selected="selected"'
```

Try remove the double `"` quotes

```
{{ $getWorker->city_id == $village->id ? 'selected=selected' : '' }}
```