# Two dynamic select boxes with data attribute in both and dependant on them

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, select, custom-data-attribute

How to get dynamic select boxes dependant on the value of data attributes in both?

Got this code

HTML

```
<select id="hours" onchange="giveSelection()">
  <option value="somethingA" data-option="1">optionA</option>
  <option value="somethingB" data-option="2">optionB</option>
</select>
<select id="paxno">
  <option data-option="1">optionC</option>
  <option data-option="1">optionD</option>
  <option data-option="2">optionE</option>
  <option data-option="1">optionF</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
var sel1 = document.querySelector('#hours');
var sel2 = document.querySelector('#paxno');
var options2 = sel2.querySelectorAll('option');

function giveSelection() {
  sel2.innerHTML = '';
  for(var i = 0; i < options2.length; i++) {
    if(options2[i].dataset.option === $("#hours").find(":selected").data("option")) {
      sel2.appendChild(options2[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

I have been trying to do this from the example given on this question on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27673937/two-html-select-boxes-linked-to-each-other), and it is working when data-attribute is non numeric but data stored in both will be numeric.

Any thoughts what I am doing wrong here? is this the best approach to 2 dynamic select boxes with both having data attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery, you might as well use it all the way.

To make it consistent, always use the jQuery `data()` method.  `data()` will always try to intelligently convert the value of the data field to another type if it can determine that it is a number, or an object, or an array, or etc.  So your original was comparing a `dataset.option` to a `data()`, using `===` which removes type coersion.  So nothing would ever be equal.

```js
var sel1 = $('#hours');
var sel2 = $('#paxno');
var options2 = sel2.find('option');

function giveSelection() {
  var target = sel1.find(':selected').data('option');
  
  sel2.empty().append(
    options2.filter(function(){
      return $(this).data('option') === target;
    })
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="hours" onchange="giveSelection()">
  <option value="somethingA" data-option="1">optionA</option>
  <option value="somethingB" data-option="2">optionB</option>
</select>
<select id="paxno">
  <option data-option="1">optionC</option>
  <option data-option="1">optionD</option>
  <option data-option="2">optionE</option>
  <option data-option="1">optionF</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Every day is a lesson, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Taplar
If I wanted to change Option F to show for both options something like below

```
var sel1 = $('#hours');
var sel2 = $('#paxno');
var options2 = sel2.find('option');

function giveSelection() {
  var target = sel1.find(':selected').data('option');
  
  sel2.empty().append(
    options2.filter(function(){
      //return $(this).data('option') === target;
    //how would you rewrite this line above to accomplish? THANKS
    })
  );
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="hours" onchange="giveSelection()">
  <option value="somethingA" data-option="1">optionA</option>
  <option value="somethingB" data-option="2">optionB</option>
</select>
<select id="paxno">
  <option data-option="1">optionC</option>
  <option data-option="1">optionD</option>
  <option data-option="2">optionE</option>
  <option data-option="1,2">optionF</option>
</select>
```