# Dynamic select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I have this select element with multiple option inside it:

```html
<select class="form-control" name="genere1">
   <option value="Alternative / Indie">Alternative / Indie</option>
   <option value="Classical Music">Classical Music</option>
   <option value="Country">Country</option>
   <option value="Easy Listening">Easy Listening</option>
   <option value="Electronic / Dance">Electronic / Dance</option>
   <option value="Hip Hop / Rap">Hip Hop / Rap</option>
   <option value="Jazz">Jazz</option>
   <option value="Latin / Reggaeton">Latin / Reggaeton</option>
   <option value="Other">Other</option>
   <option value="Pop">Pop</option>
   <option value="Reggae / Dancehall">Reggae / Dancehall</option>
   <option value="Rock">Rock</option>
   <option value="Spiritual">Spiritual</option> 
</select>
```

for every option element you see up here i have another select element. Basically, I have a series of music genres listed in a select element and, under it, the subgenres related to every single one of the "master genres".

What I would like to do is make the subgenres  visible only when the relative genre is selected. For example, if the user selects "Pop", I would like to show them the related select field containing the Pop subgenres.

My HTML markup is actually generated by a WordPress plugin and I am not able to edit it, unfortunately. This being said, I can't declare custom values inside my HTML because they are automatically generated by the plugin. I am actually looking for a simple solution, something like: if 'master genre' is 'rock', then display 'rock' input subgenres. How could I do something like this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27673937/two-html-select-boxes-linked-to-each-other

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two HTML-select boxes linked to each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27673937/two-html-select-boxes-linked-to-each-other)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Anything you can show us? How do you load the subgenres? Are those also put in the HTML? A separate `<select>` for each list of subgenres? Or a single additional `<select>` with all the subgenres (regardless their parent)? Or you want to load them via AJAX? Or...?

Comment: My HTML markup is actually generated by a WordPress plugin and I am not able to edit it, unfortunately. This being said, the links you posted won't be helpful since I can't declare custom values inside my HTML because they are automatically generated by the plugin.

Comment: None of what you just said in that last comment, is an actual answer to the question, what you have tried so far. And we don’t know what the other select elements look like either yet - so we don’t know if they have for example an ID or a class, that could be used to select them, based on the selected value of the first select you have shown.

Answer (score 0):

You could link two selects and display corresponding subgenres using `.dataset.option`. I'm afraid you won't get around a little JavaScript here.

Here's a working example for your particular use-case:

```js
const genre = document.querySelector("#genre");
const subgenre = document.querySelector("#subgenre");
const subOptions = subgenre.querySelectorAll("option");

const setValue = (newValue) => {
  subgenre.innerText = null;
  for (let i = 0; i < subOptions.length; i++)
    subOptions[i].dataset.option === newValue &&
    subgenre.appendChild(subOptions[i]);
};

setValue(genre.value);
```

```html
<select id="genre" onchange="setValue(this.value)">
  <option value="Metal">Metal</option>
  <option value="Rock">Rock</option>
</select>
<select id="subgenre">
  <option value="Metal" data-option="Metal">Thrash Metal</option>
  <option value="Metal" data-option="Metal">Death Metal</option>
  <option value="Metal" data-option="Metal">Black Metal</option>
  <option value="Rock" data-option="Rock">Classic Rock</option>
  <option value="Rock" data-option="Rock">Hard Rock</option>
</select>
```

Comment: My HTML markup is actually generated by a WordPress plugin and I am not able to edit it, unfortunately. This being said, your code won't be helpful since I can't declare custom values inside my HTML because they are automatically generated by the plugin. I was actually looking for a more simple solution, something like:
if 'master genre' is 'rock', then display 'rock' input subgenres. How could I do something like this?

Comment: It would be nice if you specified your problem in the initial question.